# How to transfer a value from a SceneDelegate file to a ViewController (Swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift, uiscenedelegate

In one of the SceneDelegate methods, I want to assign a value to a variable that is in another ViewController. How can i do this? Always getting nil. I tried different methods, but for some reason they do not work, I wanted to use the completion handler, but it seems I cannot do it in SceneDelegate methods

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
        
var viewController: ViewController?
   ...
   //This method works when I click on a cell
   func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
   if let url = URLContexts.first?.url {

      let oauthCompletion: DropboxOAuthCompletion = {
      if let authResult = $0 {
      switch authResult {
      case .success:
         self.dropboxManager.fetchFiles()
         UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey:"userAuthorizedInDropbox")
    
         //I want to assign a value here
         self.viewController?.someString = "Some Text"
    
         print("Success! User is logged into Dropbox.")
      case .cancel:
          print("Authorization flow was manually canceled by user!")
      case .error(_, let description):
          print("Error: \(String(describing: description))")
          }
      }
   }
   DropboxClientsManager.handleRedirectURL(url, completion: oauthCompletion)
  }
} 

...
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   ...
   //But it's still nil
   var someString: String?
   ...
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   dropboxManager.openDropboxAutorization(controller: self)
   }
}

.....
class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController {
let viewController: ViewController = ViewController.loadFromStoryboard()
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    viewControllers = [
            generateVC(rootViewController: viewController, image:           nil, title: "Import")
            ...
        ]

private func generateVC(rootViewController: UIViewController, image: UIImage?, title: String) -> UIViewController {
        let navigationVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootViewController)
        navigationVC.tabBarItem.image = image
        navigationVC.tabBarItem.title = NSLocalizedString(title, comment: "")
        rootViewController.navigationItem.title = NSLocalizedString(title, comment: "")
        return navigationVC
    }
   }
...
}
```

Comment: Show when and where you are allocating `viewController: ViewController?`.

Comment: I do this in the tab bar controller. I added code to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get access to your desired `ViewController` from your `rootViewController` in scene delegate. In the following example i am considering your desired view controller is in the first tab of your tab bar controller.

```
if let tabbarController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController,
   let navigationController = tabbarController.viewControllers?.first as? UINavigationController,
   let desiredController = navigationController.viewControllers.first as? ViewController {
       desiredController.someString = "some value"
}
```

But in my opinion it is not a recommended approach as there could be many cases that may depend on the application's or navigation stack's state.

What you can do is add an observer in your desired `ViewController` and post a notification from the `SceneDelegate` like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "someeventname"), object: "some value")
```

You can add and listen to the observer like this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(someEventNotificationReceived(notification:)), name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "someeventname"), object: nil)
    }
    
    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "someeventname"), object: nil)
    }

    @objc func someEventNotificationReceived(notification: Notification) {
        if let value = notification.object as? String {
            //handle the event here
        }
    }
}
```